# Can't get email from GitHub API

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to get a user's email address from GitHub, and I'm just testing the process using Postman.  I have a token that has user and user:email scopes, and hitting https://api.github.com/user gives me the user's info.  Private emails aren't visible at that endpoint, so I'm also hitting https://api.github.com/user/emails.  The email endpoint gives me a 404.

The response headers that come back with the 404 seem to say I have the right perms:

X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes →user, user:email

There is an email set up in the account.  What could be causing the 404?

Update: The troubleshooting page suggests that third-party application restrictions might be to blame.  The account I'm trying to access is part of an organization, but "Third-party application access policy" in the organization is set to "No restrictions".

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://developer.github.com/v3/troubleshooting/#why-am-i-getting-a-404-error-on-a-repository-that-exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue I was having here was looking at the wrong header.
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes is the list of scopes the endpoint wants to see.
X-OAuth-Scopes is the list of scopes you actually have.  That was empty because of a bug in the token-creating code.

Answer (score 3):

I've been facing similar issue for past several hours. Played with `X-OAuth-Scopes` and etc. Turned out my `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize` url was malformed and didn't have necessary scopes in it.

Advise: be sure you are receiving required `scope` together with your `access_token` response:

```
{"access_token":"47f31841f3b532fc4aafb3ccd924bfd0145c1c24","token_type":"bearer","scope":"user"}
```

In my case it was empty.